# Split function returning NaN for non matching patterns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting NaN for non mathcing pattern w.r.t to split in pandas.

Source Data:

```
Attr          
[ABC].[xyz]    
CDE
```

Code Used:

```
df['Extr_Attr'] = np.where((df.Attr.str.contains('.')),df['Attr'].str.split('.',1).str[1], df.Attr)

This returns NaN for data that does not have a match of '.' in source data.
```

Expected output:

```
Attr           Extr_Attr
[ABC].[xyz]    [xyz]
CDE             CDE
```

Comment: Given `df = pd.DataFrame({'Attr': ['[ABC] .[xyz]','CDE','']})`, `df.Attr.str.contains('.')` returns `True`, `True` and `False`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the last chunk after a dot (if any, else the full string).

If you want to split, use [`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) and slice the **last** item:

```
df['Extr_Attr'] = df['Attr'].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1]
```

Or more efficiently, with [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) (get all non-`.` characters at the end of the string):

```
df['Extr_Attr'] = df['Attr'].str.extract(r'([^.]+)$')
```

Output:

```
          Attr Extr_Attr
0  [ABC].[xyz]     [xyz]
1          CDE       CDE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can skip the `str.contains` and use `.split` and `.fillna`

```
df['Extr_Attr'] = df['Attr'].str.split('.').str[1].fillna(df['Attr'])

          Attr Extr_Attr
0  [ABC].[xyz]     [xyz]
1          CDE       CDE
```